# Modify UIButton width programmatically with aoutolayout ON

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I need to modify a UIButton's width at run time . The  xib file that has this button has autolayout enabled.

```
 CGFloat delta = 40.0;
            self.Button.frame = CGRectMake(self.Button.frame.origin.x - delta,
                                                    self.Button.frame.origin.y,
                                                    self.Button.frame.size.width + delta,
                                                    self.Button.frame.size.height
                                                    );
```

How to do this with autolayout on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an outlet to the constraint that specifies the width. When you want to change the frame, don't. Change the constraint.